# Syntax error in FROM clause Access

Tags: database, c#-2.0, accessdatasource

I want to read the data from Access Database in order to check if a password is correct or not. I use this code:

```
var check=false;
OleDbCommand c = new OleDbCommand();
c.Connection = co //the connection to the Database;
c.CommandText = "select * FROM User Where user_name='"+usee+"'"; 
OleDbDataReader re = c.ExecuteReader();
while (re.Read())
{
    if (re.ToString() == pasy)
    {
        check = true;
    }
}
```

It gives me a "Syntax error in FROM clause." when the code executes.

Comment: User is a reserved word in Access. I think  you can use backticks to allow it, but suggest changing that table name to `Users` or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"User" is a reserved word for Access.

Here is a list of reserved words :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335/en-us

and here is a page describing that problem :
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181489/en-us